# flutter add data to json only if it does not already exist

Tags: flutter

I have following Model

`product_model.dart`

```
class ProductModel {
  String status;
  String message;
  List<Results> results;

  ProductModel({this.status, this.message, this.results});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      results = new List<Results>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    if (this.results != null) {
      data['data'] = this.results.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Results {
  String id;
  String productCode;
  String category;
  String title;
  String isActive;

  Results(
      {this.id,
      this.productCode,
      this.category,
      this.title,
      this.isActive,
      });

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    productCode = json['product_code'];
    category = json['category'];
    title = json['title'];
    isActive = json['is_active'];

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['product_code'] = this.productCode;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['is_active'] = this.isActive;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I have a functionality to save products to favorites. The favorites will be saved as json in a file.

```
import 'package:example/utils/favstorage.dart';
import 'package:example/models/product_model.dart';

class FavoriteProducts {
  FavoritesStorage storage = FavoritesStorage();
  List<ProductModel> favorites = [];

  Future addFavorite(ProductModel products) async {
      favorites.add(products);
      await storage.writeFavorites(favorites);
  }
}
```

I want to add product to favorites only if its not there. How can I update the `addFavorite` method so that if particular **`id` doesnot exist** then only proceed adding to favorites. 
I am new to flutter. Can anybody help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

You can use and indexWhere to search your list for an item with the same id, like this:

```
Future addFavorite(ProductModel products) async {
  if(favorites.indexWhere((listProduct) => listProduct.id == products.id) == -1){
    favorites.add(products);
    await storage.writeFavorites(favorites);
  }
}
```

-1 means there was no item, if there was the item it would have returned it from the list.

Comment: It should be -1 when it is not in the list. Documentation: "Returns -1 if element is not found." https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html

Comment: Doesn't work, error: The getter 'id' isn't defined for the class 'ProductModel'

Comment: I see now that your ProductModel doesn't have an id. How do you identify each product if it doesn't have an id? Do you actually want to add the results instead? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you @WatsMyName I don't know where I got 0 from.

Comment: There is a result class in `ProductModel`, all product information is in that class. Please see my first code in the post. THanks

Comment: My response was based on what you said "I want to add product to favorites only if its not there. How can I update the addFavorite method so that if particular id doesnot exist then only proceed adding to favorites" But the model you are trying to insert into the Favourites doesn't have an id. It's a property (results) of that model is a List of Results, which then have ids. The solution for this is more complex than you were assuming. As you would have to iterate through the results of each Product model and then compare to the ones already saved.

Comment: Does this mean the favourites are a compilation of all the results of the different ProductModels that you want to add to favourites?

Comment: Yes, the json format from external api is always same. `ProductModel` is used by all product listing widgets through out app including Favorites as well.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding your model:

1. ProductModel has List
2. Results has id.

How to see if provided ProductModel can be added to favorite:

1. Take favorites list and look in List.
2. in each product model liik in List.
3. for each Results check if there id is same as any Results in List of provided ProductModel to the method.
4. If every thing is false, add ProductModel to favorite.

Following is the code for your reference:

```
Future addFavorite(ProductModel products) async {
    bool containsId = favorites.any((ProductModel model){
        return model.results.any((Results result){
            return products.results.any((Results resultInProducts) => resultInProducts.id == result.id);
        });
    });

    if(!containsId){
        favorites.add(products);
        await storage.writeFavorites(favorites);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment. *If this answer helps you then please accept and up-vote the answer.*

Comment: I haven't had chance to test your code, I am out from my home, i will accept your answer once I will check it when I am back.

Comment: Okay, hope it works for you.. in case of any doubt please comment..